# Creating a FadeIn/FadeOut Animation with a set delay in HTML/CSS/JS (StreamLabs)

Tags: javascript, html, css, fadein, fadeout

Streamlabs has a feature which lets you *delay* the **fadeIn** animation of a text after a certain time (without any extra code).
This feature is pretty much not usable though. There is also no option to control the **fadeOut** animation.

If you define the **fadeIn** *delay* to be ~4s: It jumps (after 4s) straight from 0% opacity to 50% opacity and after another second it jumps to 100% opacity. There is no fluid animation. However, this does not happen if you have the "text delay" on 0s. Everything looks fine if you keep it at 0s.

So I was wondering how to implement my own version of a fadeInFadeOut animation with either HTML, CSS or JS.

My goal is to have a text appear after 4 seconds with a **fadeIn** animation (duration 1 second), then it should stay **visible** for 3 seconds. Eventually the text should disappear with a **fadeOut** animation (duration 1 second) after 8 seconds.

Is this effect achievable with such a structure?

> animation: fadeOut x y forwards;

Appreciate all the help! Thanks!

**EDIT** Here's the updated code from Streamlabs with the CSS FadeIn/Out animation.

````
```HTML
<div id="alert-image-wrap"
 <div id="alert-image">{img}</div>
</div>

<div id="alert-text-wrap">
<div id="alert-text">
<div id="alert-message">{messageTemplate}</div>
<div id="alert-user-message">{userMessage}</div>
</div>
</div>
```


``` CSS (most important parts)
#alert-text {
z-index: 6;
 position: relative;
top: -920px;
}
#alert-text-wrap {
z-index: 6;
position: relative;
opacity:1;
animation: fadein-fadeout 9s forwards; 
}
*//credits @Cedric Cholley*
@keyframes fadein-fadeout {
...
100% {opacity: 0} /* (8 + 1) 9s / 9s = 100%  */
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is achievable with CSS animation indeed. You only need to make some computations (see my comments on the CSS code.

```css
.fadein-fadeout {
 animation: fadein-fadeout 9s forwards; 
}

@keyframes fadein-fadeout {
  0% {opacity: 0}
  44.4% {opacity: 0} /* 4s / 9s ~ 44.4…% */
  55.6% {opacity: 1} /* (4 + 1) 5s / 9s ~ 55.6…% */
  88.9% {opacity: 1} /* (5 + 3) 8s / 9s ~ 88.9…% */
  100% {opacity: 0} /* (8 + 1) 9s / 9s = 100%  */
```

```html
<h1 class="fadein-fadeout">A random text</h1>
```

Comment: The timing is perfect and the transition also works, the text won't appear in full opacity though. (Even though the opacity is set to '1').
It's more at a 20% opacity now.
I included all the major parts of my code in my question above. :)
Thanks!

Comment: I can't make the code in the question work. At some point don't you need in `#alert-text` to change `top: -920px` in `top: 0`

Comment: I guess I could use a seperate class to transform the actual text. Need the text in this certain position though, I don't know how else I'd achieve that effect. Thanks for your Help! I think this case is mostly closed, your answers helped me alot!